# Is it bad practice to call an observer in a destructor?

Tags: c++

I have an object that sends a signal when a group of tasks completes. These tasks are executed independently in a thread pool. I want to send a notification to an observer when all of the tasks in a group are complete.

Essentially this boils down to a reference counting scheme. When ref=0, I send the notification. One implementation of this would be to leverage boost smart pointers (or any ref counted auto).

```
class TaskCompletionNotifier {
  ~TaskCompletionNotifier() {
    _listener->notify();
  }

  setListener(listener);

  Listener _listener;
}

class Task {
  boost::shared_ptr<TaskCompletionNotifier> _notifier; 
}
```

My question is, is it bad practice to perform this call-out in the destructor of an object?

Comment: this is not question about exception handling, "is it bad practice if it throws, or if it doesn't throw" but in general, is it bad practice to notify from desctructor

Comment: @lizusek if it can throw then the question is ultimately moot.

Comment: As Bartek hinted, it's not a bad idea in itself, but you cannot have exceptions thrown while the destructor is being executed. This will simply terminate your program.

Comment: of course but this is not a subject of the matter here, assumption is that this is OK from exception handing point of view

Comment: why don't you notify after destruction?

Comment: @lizusek I'd rather not make any assumptions. That's why I asked in *a comment*, not made *an answer*.

Comment: you always make many assumptions, otherwise you cannot say anything

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this inherently bad? No.

Does it open up potential pitfalls? Yes.

Make sure you don't allow any exceptions to escape the destructor, and you're best off making sure that `_listener->notify()` doesn't end up modifying any member data of this object: it's *safe* and *okay* if it does, but may be confusing and/or mess up your destructor's close-down logic.

Other than that, go for it.

Comment: I think OP knows that it opens potential and this is why he asked, he also knows that this isn't inherently bad, and this is why he asked.

Comment: @lizusek So ... you're saying the OP already knows all the answers to his question, and we should just ignore him?

Comment: No, I refer to @Lightness comment "This is OK if it's OK" Not really useful". His introduction is similar.

Comment: @lizusek: I don't see how. The OP asks whether this is bad practice; I say no. What _you_ did was to say "it's fine as long as the language makes it fine", which does not answer the OP's question but instead reforms the question.

Answer (score -4):

> Is it bad practice to call an observer in a destructor?

No. It is not.

But it opens up potential for many pitfalls so make sure you do it without violating of C++ rules (C++ standard). In particular:

- make sure exception are handled so that no exception will propagate out of destructor

Comment: "This is OK if it's OK" Not really useful

Comment: Your answer does seem unfairly downvoted for the state it's currently in, but judging from Lightness' comment, I'm guessing the original version didn't include the *exception swallowing* bit, which makes it unworthy of even a comment, let alone an answer. Also, your edit seems to *borrow* phrases straight out of Lightness' answer.

Comment: yes, it did included the mention about exceptions propagating out of destructor. Yes because only the begining of answer was different, so I would like not to give anyone opportunity to downvote and use same words as his answer. Apparently there is more that counts, not only answer itself.

Comment: No, it did not include any mention of exceptions whatsoever at that time. Don't lie.

Comment: Well yes it did. Even if it did not it did after edit, about 10 seconds after it was published so downvotes should be cleared. I also think my answer was better than yours even taking into account only the introduction. Your introduction contains very few of information.